# Draw a line from the camera position to the origin

Tags: three.js

Using threejs, I'm trying to draw a line from the camera position to the origin.
I expect that the line will always point to the middle of the screen (assuming that the renedered scene is viewed from the camera origin)
but it does not (the line always points towards the side of the screen).
The code below is a subset of the formal threejs webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes.html example.
I added the function draw_line_from_camera_to_origin(scene, camera)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Avner

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - geometry - extrude shapes</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #222;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            a {
                color: #f80;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="../build/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer, controls;

            init();
            animate();

                        function draw_line_from_camera_to_origin(scene, camera)
                        {
                                // Draw line from camera to origin
                                var pointA2 = new THREE.Vector3( camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z );
                                var pointB2 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

                                var geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry();
                                geometry2.vertices.push( pointA2 );
                                geometry2.vertices.push( pointB2 );
                                var material2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 'yellow' } );
                                var line2 = new THREE.Line( geometry2, material2 );
                                scene.add( line2 );
                        }

            function init() {

                var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
                info.style.position = 'absolute';
                info.style.top = '10px';
                info.style.width = '100%';
                info.style.textAlign = 'center';
                info.style.color = '#fff';
                info.style.link = '#f80';
                info.innerHTML = '<a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> webgl - geometry extrude shapes';
                document.body.appendChild( info );

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x222222 );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 0, 500 );

                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.minDistance = 200;
                controls.maxDistance = 500;

                scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );

                var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.copy( camera.position );
                scene.add( light );

                //

                var closedSpline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
                    new THREE.Vector3( -60, -100,  60 ),
                    new THREE.Vector3( -60,   20,  60 ),
                    new THREE.Vector3( -60,  120,  60 ),
                    new THREE.Vector3(  60,   20, -60 ),
                    new THREE.Vector3(  60, -100, -60 )
                ] );

                closedSpline.curveType = 'catmullrom';
                closedSpline.closed = true;

                var extrudeSettings = {
                    steps           : 100,
                    bevelEnabled    : false,
                    extrudePath     : closedSpline
                };


                var pts = [], count = 3;

                for ( var i = 0; i < count; i ++ ) {

                    var l = 20;

                    var a = 2 * i / count * Math.PI;

                    pts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( Math.cos( a ) * l, Math.sin( a ) * l ) );

                }

                var shape = new THREE.Shape( pts );

                var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );

                var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xb00000, wireframe: false } );

                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                scene.add( mesh );


                                draw_line_from_camera_to_origin(scene, camera);
            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                controls.update();

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the location of the other point.

When you first create the line you tell it a point in space and it never moves from there. It may seem like its moving around but that's just because it is a very long line.

So you need to make geometry2 a global variable (at the top):

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, controls, geometry2;
```

Then remove `var` when you declare geometry2 in `draw_line_from_camera_to_origin`
Then your animation loop should be:

```js
function animate() {

    geometry2.vertices[0].x = camera.position.x;
    geometry2.vertices[0].y = camera.position.y;
    geometry2.vertices[0].z = camera.position.z;
    geometry2.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    controls.update();

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Now when you move the camera you see the line move with it then drift back to the camera's position. I'm not sure why it does that, I was actually expecting the line to be invisible (because lines have 0 width, and its pointing directly at the camera).